# Assigning object properties

Tags: php

I have simple class:

```
class Pet { 
 var $pet_type;
 var $pet_exist = true;
 var $pet_name;
 var $pet_owner;
 public static  $pet_types= array (1 =>"Nothing to choose...",
                          2 =>"Dog",
                          3 =>"Cat",
                          4 =>"Guinea pig",
                          5 =>"Turtle",
                          6 =>"Fishes",
                          7 =>"Other");

 function setAttr($pet_exist,$pet_type,$pet_name,$pet_owner) {
    $this->pet_exist=$pet_exist;
    $this->pet_name=$pet_name;
    $this->pet_type=$pet_type;
    $this->pet_owner=$pet_owner;
 }
```

I try this

```
$pet = new Pet;
$owner = 12;
$pet =  new Pet;
$pet->setAttr("12","12","12",$owner);
var_dump($pet);
```

I see the following result:

```
object(Pet)#2 (4) { ["pet_type"]= string(2) "12" ["pet_exist"]= string(2) "12" ["pet_name"]= string(2) "12" ["pet_owner"]= int(12) }
```

Why isn't the property `pet_owner` set?

Comment: `["pet_owner"]= int(12)`. It **is** set, what's wrong ?

Comment: `pet_owner` has been set, to `12`, exactly as it should be

Comment: Why are you instantiating Pet twice? and assigning the object to the same variable in each case?

Comment: What the old php (v4) style? Tovarisch Petrov vy po russki govorite?

Comment: Deep, pochemy old?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it as string use like this,

`$owner = '12';` instead of `$owner = 12;`

otherwise it will show property **int(12)**,

and also use `$pet = new Pet;` this once only..